# We are trying to call api and we are get all responce but they not display on text view

Tags: android

[ServiceClass Code where we want to access request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqvvM.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please post your code as text in your question, don't link to a resource or post it as an image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1

Comment: there is some problem with your code. Probably your views misplaced in layout, probably you are setting their text on non-ui thread, or 100 more possible causes

Answer (score 0):

There must be something that is hiding your view otherwise i can not see any issue related to retrofit, because i can see there is value in the string variable and is the only value you are setting into your textview.

So my suggestion is please look into your XML file whether you view is getting hide or not, 
if not then second Possibility can be your view is getting hide from java file or it is overlapping by other view.

Comment: No sir I am checking again but not  hide view and no overlapping textView

Comment: Thanks sir actually  i am not giving the textsize